# Is this set closed under countable intersections?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

If we have $J$ = {all intervals contained in $[0,1]$} and $B_0$= {all finite unions of elements of $J$}, would $B_0$ be closed under countable intersections?

EDIT: I believe that it is indeed closed under countable intersections. I am wondering if I am correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cantor set (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) is the intersection of countably many elements of $B_0$, but is clearly not in $B_0$.

Comment: Okay, I can see this. However, I am assuming the cantor set is allowed to be infinite? (The Wikipedia page defined $C_n$. $C_0$, $C_1$ etc are finite unions of elements of $B_0$ and are therefore in $B_0$ though.  For example $[0,1] = [0,\frac{1}{2}] \cup [\frac{1}{2},1]$, $C_1 = [0,\frac{1}{4}] \cup [\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{3}] \cup [\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{4}] \cup [\frac{3}{4},1]$ etc.

Comment: @user265678 What do you mean "the Cantor set is allowed to be infinite?" Yes, it is an infinite intersection of elements of $B_0$ - but a *countable* intersection of elements of $B_0$, so it is allowed by your question. Note that clearly $B_0$ is closed under *finite* intersections. You may be interested in the Borel hierarchy, which explores the theme of closing under countable unions/intersections a bit more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_hierarchy.

Comment: I was looking at wikipedia's definition of $C_n$, which I guess is not the cantor set but used in constructing the cantor set? My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

No, consider for example
$$ A_k = (0,\tfrac1{2k}] \cup [\tfrac1{2k-1},\tfrac1{2k-2}] \cup \ldots \cup [\tfrac15,\tfrac14]\cup[\tfrac13,\tfrac12] $$
which are all in $B_0$, but
$$\bigcap_k A_k = \bigcup_n [\tfrac1{2n+1},\tfrac1{2n}] $$
is not in $B_0$.